# Query a realmObject where it realmList equals to another realmList

Tags: android, realm, realm-list

I would like to know if there is a direct way to query realmObjects where its realmList equals another realmList.

Example:

```
public class Tags extends RealmObject{
    @PrimaryKey
    private String ID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

    private String tag;
}

public class Article extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private String ID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

    private RealmList<Tags> tags;
}

RealmList<Tags> userTags;
Article article = mDB.where(Article.class).equalTo("tags", userTags).findFirst();
```

Comment: Where do you get `userTags` from? Does it belong to a RealmObject called `User`?

Comment: Not necessarily. The app has a search engine where users can insert tags to find articles. I would like to return all articles that match that tags criteria. Any idea on how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but you can create a link query with [`in` query condition](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmQuery.html#in-java.lang.String-java.lang.String:A-).

```
RealmList<Tags> userTags = ...;
Set<String> tags = new LinkedHashSet<>();
for(Tags tag : userTags) {
    ids.add(tag.getTag());
}
String[] tagArray = tags.toArray(new String[tags.size()]);
Article article = mDB.where(Article.class).in("tags.tag", tagIdArray).findFirst();
```

Comment: Cool, I think it could work, let me try it and test it.